# Jersey 1 ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, jersey-2.0, weld, jersey-1.0

I have a Jersey 1 ContainerResponseFilter in a shared library, which I register in Jersey 1 web services by specifying the package this filter exists in inside the web.xml eg.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.xxx.utils.jersey
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.utils.jersey.CrossDomainFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.utils.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

I am now trying to use this shared library in a Jersey 2 web service which instead of using the web.xml to configure Jersey uses a class annotated with `@ApplicationPath` and extending the Jersey `ResourceConfig`. Inside this class I am not specifying the package of this Jersey 1 filter anywhere.

The problem I am getting is because this Jersey 2 web service doesn't include any Jersey 1 dependencies in the war I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` during deployment of the webservice for `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter`

Here is an example of how I am creating my config

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    private static final String RESOURCE_PACKAGE = "com.xxx.services.rest";

    public AppConfig()
    {
        packages(RESOURCE_PACKAGE);
        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage(RESOURCE_PACKAGE);
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:7001");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/usr/");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can make sure this Jersey 1 class is not loaded from the shared library, can I explicitly exclude the package?

EDIT:

A bit more investigation seems to imply it's something to do with CDI, the `ContainerResponseFilter` is annotated as a `@Producer`. If I remove the annotation from the class then I no longer receive the exception.

The container I am using is weblogic 12.2.1 which I believe uses Weld as its CDI provider. So I created a beans.xml with the following as indicated by this bit of Weld [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.16.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e5774)

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans">
   <weld:scan>
     <weld:exclude name="com.xxx.utils.jersey.**"/>
   </weld:scan>
 </beans>
```

But it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Any ideas?